# undefined lame decode function

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, lame

I'm trying to add MP3 read and write capabilities to my Android app.  I'm using the lame4android app as a starting point.  Encoding a file works for me, but I'm having a problem with the decode functions -- I'm getting undefined references to the decode functions.

Here are excerpts from my wrapper.c:

```
#include "libmp3lame/lame.h"
#include "jni.h"

lame_t lame;

jint Java_com_intonia_dandy_WavStream_initEncoder(JNIEnv *env,
                                                  jobject jobj,
                                                  jint in_num_channels,
                                                  jint in_samplerate)
{
    lame = lame_init();
    ...
    return lame_init_params(lame);
}

hip_t hip;

jint Java_com_intonia_dandy_WavStream_initDecoder(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj)
{
    hip = hip_decode_init();
    return hip != 0;
}
```

And here are the declarations from lame.h:

```
lame_global_flags * CDECL lame_init(void);

typedef hip_global_flags *hip_t;
hip_t CDECL hip_decode_init(void);
```

I'm getting an error message:

```
C:/ACode/dandy/src/main/jni/./wrapper.c:62: undefined reference to `hip_decode_init`
```

I'm also getting undefined references to `hip_decode` and and `hip_decode_exit`.  But `lame_init`, `lame_init_params`, `lame_encode_buffer`, and `lame_encode_flush` do not generate any errors.  I get these errors using the command line to run ndk-build, and I get the same errors when I let Android Studio manage the compilation.

How are the `lame_*` functions different from the `hip_decode_*` functions?  Should I be using the deprecated `lame_decode_*`?

EDIT: I'm looking at the output of the ndk-build command.  The .c files are listed on the console as they are compiled.  `hip_decode_init` is defined in `jni/libmp3lame/mpglib_interface.c`, but `mpglib_interface` is not getting compiled, even though it's listed in `jni/Android.mk`.  Why not???

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the LAME library as distributed does not have decoding enabled.  To get it working, I had to do the following:

1. Add `#define HAVE_MPGLIB 1` to `mpglib_interface.c`
2. Copy all .c and .h files from the mpglib directory of the LAME distribution.
3. Edit Android.mk to include the .c files from mpglib.

EDIT: instead of modifying mpglib_interface.c to define `HAVE_MPGLIB`,
it's better to set compilation flags.

Working with Android Studio 2+, build.gradle should contain

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "libmp3lame"
            cFlags "-DSTDC_HEADERS -DHAVE_MPGLIB"
        }
    }
}
```

Or in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS = -DSTDC_HEADERS -DHAVE_MPGLIB
```